# Powershell V1 v V3 - Pop-Up windows gone

Tags: powershell

When I did `$name = Read-Host 'What is your name?'` in Powershell V1 it would ask the question in a pop-up window.

With Powershell V3 it just asks in the console window. Is there a way to force `Read-Host` questions to pop-up still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to skin this cat.  Here is one:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')    
$name = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter your name", "Name", "$env:username")
```

And with the `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")` and 
`[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")` assemblies, you can make a full-featured, customized input box just like you would with C#.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'm VB.Net more than C#. Do you know any good sites or books I can read about this stuff? I like the idea of a proper graphical GUI with drop-downs, check-boxes etc.

Comment: Yeah, check out what this guy does with System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms assemblies. You can add all the buttons and drop-downs and controls you can imagine: http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2012/10/display-inputbox-with-powershell_23.html

Comment: One thing with this. The pop-ups are popping out behind my main PowerShell window. Any way of making them appear in the foreground?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978727/focus-window-created-by-powershell-script